# Set Cache-Control header in response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm using Rails (v3.2.21) for an API application and trying to set the "Cache-Control" header in my responses so that my client app can cache them. However, the header values on the actual response are still using the default values (checked using Advanced Rest Client plugin in Chrome).

From Googlage, it seems that the `expires_in` method is the way to do this:

```
expires_in 3.hours, :public => true
```

However, when I make a request to the resource, it always returns (the default?):

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, private, max-age=0
```

When I do a binding.pry right after the `expires_in` and check `response.headers`, it is empty... seems wrong too.

I'm doing the above in `before_filter` in my controller, and have also tried right before I call `render` to return my response.

I should add that I've tried to set the "Cache-Control" header manually using `response.headers["CacheControl"] = "blah"` but that doesn't work either and I've read elsewhere that Rails doesn't allow this anyway.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you reproducing problem in dev environment?

Comment: Yes, this is in a dev environment. However, in my config I am setting perform_caching = true which as far as I am aware will allow caching to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was actually down to some other config that I had in the app which was preventing caching from happening (specifically the `Bullet.disable_browser_cache` setting which was true for development environments). Setting this to false meant that caching worked properly.

Comment: what was the correct way to use expires_in 3.hours, :public => true to set cache control?

Comment: @MicFin , it's been a while since I looked at this, but what I was doing is as follows:
`expires_in(1.year, "must-revalidate" => true`
So I guess you could try:
`expires_in(30.hours), "public" => true`

(I haven't tested this btw!)